# error while exporting data in an ssis package to an excel destination

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I just moved my ssis package from my desktop to my server.The package exports data from sqlserver to an excel sheet.  I see the following error when I try to run the package. The error occurs in the excel destination of the dataflow task.

```
Error at Package [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_ERROR.  The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. Error code: 0x00000000.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".

Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Destination [16]]: SSIS Error Code 


[Excel Destination [16]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC020  9302.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
```

I also made the following changes as I had errors before and the package wouldnt even run .

Set the delay validation to false on the data flow task.
set the Run64bitruntime under the project properties to true

Can anyone tell me what I need to do ?

PS : I am running the package on the server and MS excel is not installed on it . Could that be causing the error ?

Comment: DelayValidation should be true on **both** the Data Flow and the Connection Manager. Also, ensure you are running this in 32 bit mode

Answer (score 2):

> PS : I am running the package on the server and MS excel is not
>   installed on it . Could that be causing the error ?

Yes

I did also find another thread describing a solution:

[HOW TO: FIX ERROR - "the 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Which does not involve installing the full version of Office:

> NOTE: this DOES work for office 2010 even though it is for 2007
>   office, dont ask me why it just does :)
>
> 1. download and install this: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734
> 2. in VS click add data source, follow the wizard and enjoy! :)

They are using Visual Studio but I imagine you should be able to run your SSIS package without having to "add a data source" as it's looking for the COM componet`microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0` which should now be registered.

Comment: OK ! Is there a way I can rectify it because I cannot install excel since its a server ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this once and had to save the excel sheets as .csv and use a flat file connection manager:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140266.aspx

Answer (score 1):

an alternative is using 32bit option in SSIS project.
Right Click on Solution and select Properties > Select Debugging and specify FALSE for option Run64Bitruntime